# What is causing the error `string.split is not a function`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

Why am I getting...

> Uncaught TypeError: string.split is not a function

...when I run...

```js
var string = document.location;
var split = string.split('/');
```

Comment: `document.location` is an object. Try: `var string=document.location.href`

Comment: I have just been trying to do exactly this

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Change this...

```
var string = document.location;
```

to this...

```
var string = document.location + '';
```

This is because `document.location` is a [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object). The default `.toString()` returns the location in string form, so the concatenation will trigger that.

---

You could also use [`document.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/document.URL) to get a string.

Comment: Would not it be cleaner to call `toString()` instead of hacky concatenation?

Comment: @bažmegakapa: Yeah, that's a matter of preference. The `+ ''` is a pretty common trick for string coercion, but some people prefer the `toString()` method. I wouldn't consider it any more hacky than using the unary `+` for number conversion.

Comment: That is just as ugly. There is `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`. There is also `Number()`. The `+` is shorter of course, but less readable for someone not used to hacky code or less experienced.

Comment: the `+ ''` method doesn't change anything for me in Chrome Browser but `toString()` does.

Comment: @MA-Maddin: Did you do `my_string + "".split()`? If so, you need parens since `+` has a lower precedence than `.`. So like this: `(my_string + "").split()`

Comment: @squint The problem was, that I was trying to override the object's property with the string: `myObj.data = myObj.data + '';`. This wasn't possible / the property remained an object. If this is default javascript behavior I will delete my comments.

Comment: @MA-Maddin: Object properties are able to be set as non-writeable. Were you able to assign any other values to `myObj.data`?

Answer (score 93):

maybe

```
string = document.location.href;
arrayOfStrings = string.toString().split('/');
```

assuming you want the current url

Answer (score 14):

run this

```
// you'll see that it prints Object
console.log(typeof document.location);
```

you want `document.location.toString()` or `document.location.href`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realized I converted my var from string to object. Your solution gave me an idea to check back my code.

Answer (score 9):

`document.location` isn't a string.

You're probably wanting to use `document.location.href` or `document.location.pathname` instead.

Comment: lol. 4 answers (at least) at the same time. I shouldn't look at the newest questions on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

In clausule if, use `()`.
For example:

```
stringtorray = "xxxx,yyyyy,zzzzz";
if (xxx && (stringtoarray.split(',') + "")) { ...
```