# How to get a random line from a text file and print it out

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I'm trying to use a discord.js bot command to take a random line from a text file and send it on chat, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Also, would it be easier to use .JSON for this task? Thanks in advance. I tried this [Grabbing a random line from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392059/grabbing-a-random-line-from-file) but it still wouldn't work

```
 if (msg.content === "give random data") {

        //print out a random line from a .txt file

    }
```

Comment: Use the 'fs' module of nodejs

Comment: Assuming you used that code, I would output the lines variable so you can see that the file is read correctly, maybe also the first line of lines. so `console.log(lines);` and then `console.log(lines[0])` before you try to use lines to select the random line.

Answer (score 1):

how did it not work? was there any error messages?
json is easier but not by much, if its not a data structure i think you should use txt file.

you should read the file, cache it, and then when someone does that command just
return `lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)]`;

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is in the JS file:

```
const data = `{
  "1": "hello world",
  "2": "cat dog",
  "3": "john smith"
}`;

client.on('message', msg => {

  if (msg.content === "give random data") {
    let obj = JSON.parse(data);
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    let randomLine = obj[String(index)];
    msg.channel.send(randomLine);
  }

});
```