# JScript Split String Result by \n delimieter

Tags: string, split, scripting, jscript

I am very new to JScript, and windows scripting in general, and I have some data which I have read from a file and converted to a string, I want to split this data into two data arrays so they can be used separately. The data looks like this when I output from the file, showing the two parts which are deliminated by a newline character. If I split the data using (" ") it correctly separates each number, however I want to do this after separating the two sets of data first.

```
5.000000 9.000000 3.000000 7.000000 1.000000 4.000000 6.000000 2.000000 8.000000 0.000000 
2464.000000 2464.000000 616.000000 2464.000000 154.000000 1232.000000 2464.000000 308.000000 2464.000000 77.000000
```

When I  run code to split the two parts I receive this result

```
res 0 = 5.000000 9.000000 3.000000 7.000000 1.000000 4.000000 6.000000 2.000000 8.000000 0.000000 ,2464.000000 2464.000000 616.000000 2464.000000 154.000000 1232.000000 2464.000000 308.000000 2464.000000 77.000000 
res 1 = undefined
```

This is the code I used to generate the above outputs

```js
//Outputs 1
for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  println(data[i]);
  }
data = data + ''; //Convert Data from object to String
var res = data.split("\n")
//Outputs 2
console.log("res 0 = " + res[0]);
console.log("res 1 = " + res[1]);
```

This is the result I want

```js
res 0 = 5.000000 9.000000 3.000000 7.000000 1.000000 4.000000 6.000000 2.000000 8.000000 0.000000
res 1 = 2464.000000 2464.000000 616.000000 2464.000000 154.000000 1232.000000 2464.000000 308.000000 2464.000000 77.000000
```

Edit: Code that reads the data

```js
function dataRead(fname) {
  console.log("Reading sequence...");
  var fs = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var lines = [];
  var stream = fs.OpenTextFile(fname);
  while(!stream.AtEndOfStream) {
    lines.push(stream.ReadLine());
  }

  stream.Close();

  return lines;
}
```

Edit: Matlab Code that writes the data

```matlab
data = [T.seq; T.duration_bits];
    newfile = [dir '\' name '.txt']
    fp = fopen(newfile, 'w');
    fprintf(fp,'%f ', data(1,:));
    fprintf(fp,'\n');
    fprintf(fp,'%f ', data(2,:));
    fclose(fp);
```

(object to string was from [What is causing the error `string.split is not a function`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145946/what-is-causing-the-error-string-split-is-not-a-function))

Comment: Have you checked if ```data``` contains ```\n```? Where is the code that reads your file?

Comment: I have added the code that reads the file, the data is generated using MATLAB, and I use fprintf to specifically add '\n' to the data after that line

Comment: Okay, so now I see that you are returning ```lines``` from ```dataRead```. My assumption is that you size of lines is ```2```. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: So why don't you split (by spaces) ```lines[0]``` into ```res0``` and ```lines[1]``` into ```res1```?

Comment: I would like a way to do this more generally as `data` won't always be 2 lines, and I am using this example to try and find a way to handle arbitrarily large sets of data

Comment: Ah yes, okay, I see what you mean, I am very dumb

Comment: Also, please remember that functions that read lines from files across many languages remove the ```\n```.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer, thank you, I have posted the full code that gave me the answer I wanted, along with its outputs below

```js
var data = import_sequence(path_func, path, file, ext);
for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  println(data[i]);
  }
var seq = data[0];
seq = seq.split(" ").map(Number);
seq.pop();
console.log("seq = "+ seq);

var dur_bits = data[1];
dur_bits = dur_bits.split(" ").map(Number);
dur_bits.pop();
console.log("dur_bits = " + dur_bits);
}
console.log("dur = " + dur);
```

Output

```
Reading sequence...
Data Line0 = 5.000000 9.000000 3.000000 7.000000 1.000000 4.000000 6.000000 2.000000 8.000000 0.000000 
Data Line1 = 2464.000000 2464.000000 616.000000 2464.000000 154.000000 1232.000000 2464.000000 308.000000 2464.000000 77.000000 
seq = 5,9,3,7,1,4,6,2,8,0
dur_bits = 2464,2464,616,2464,154,1232,2464,308,2464,77
```