# Get array from a json file to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, file

pre-script: I'm a very noob at javascript and I'm using my c# knoledge to create a Discord bot in javascript, so I'm sorry if this question is too dumb.

I have a code to write down in a json file an array called `tarefas` using this code:

```
tarefas.push(subcomando);

bot.tarefasFile ['wait tasks'] = {
    task : tarefas
}
fs.writeFile('./tarefas.json', JSON.stringify(bot.tarefasFile,null,4),
err => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
cmd.channel.send('`' + subcomando + '` added to tasks.');
```

(`subcomando` is the message when someone sends `w_add task_[subcomando]` in my Discord server. Example below)

The output json file `tarefas.json` is:

```
{
"wait tasks": {
    "tasks": []
}
```

For now, my code resets the value of the array `tarefas` when the bot restarts, so I want to reload its values from the tarefas.json file, precisely from the `"tasks": []` array. How do I do that?

extra:
Example from when the json file is populated with some "tasks":

[screenshot of my discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMKRZ.png)

```
{
    "wait tasks": {
        "tasks": [
            "hi",
            "hello",
            "bye",
            "math exam tomorrow"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes by using txt file instead of json file.
write:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-program-to-write-data-in-a-text-file/
read:
[Reading local text file into a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857458/reading-local-text-file-into-a-javascript-array)
fix the split function not working:
[What is causing the error `string.split is not a function`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145946/what-is-causing-the-error-string-split-is-not-a-function)